# FileField Size and Name in Template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-file-upload

How do I get the size and name of a FileField in a template?

My model is setup like this:

```
class PDFUpload(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_pdf)
```

My template is setup like this:

```
{% for download in downloads %}
    <div class="download">
        <div class="title"> Name</div>
        <div class="size">64.5 MB</div>
        <div class="desc">{{download.desc}}</div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I display the file name and size?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Once you've got access to the value of a [`FileField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField), you've got a value of type [`File`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/), which has the following methods:

[`File.name`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File.name):
The name of file including the relative path from MEDIA_ROOT.

[`File.size`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File.size)
The size of the file in bytes.

So you can do this in your template:

```
{% for download in downloads %}
    <div class="download">
        <div class="title">{{download.file.name}}</div>
        <div class="size">{{download.file.size}} bytes</div>
        <div class="desc">{{download.desc}}</div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

To get a more human-readable filesize (for those of your users who would be confused by seeing 64.5 MB as 67633152 bytes - I call them wusses), then you might be interested in the [`filesizeformat`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#filesizeformat) filter, for turning sizes in bytes into things like  `13 KB`, `4.1 MB`, `102 bytes`, etc, which you use in your template like this:

```
<div class="size">{{download.file.size|filesizeformat}}</div>
```

Comment: +1, but would you care to expand on "Once you've got access to the value of a `FileField`, you've got a value of type `File`"? When working with an instance of `FileField` as above (with `download.file`) how do you magically find yourself with an instance of `File` instead? I see quite a lot of this kind of stuff with Django. It can be confusing. And if you could point to any documentation for this, it would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Possibly this link [Django Model field reference:Field types](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/fields/#field-types), which says "When you access a FileField on a model, you are given an instance of FieldFile as a proxy for accessing the underlying file." is relevant. I still think it is magical though.