# Get file name from Django imagefield before submit with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, django-models

Its the basic Django image file upload process form. The image model is using the ImageField class. I have a custom display button over the default upload button that normally displays the name of the image to the side of it. I need to be able to grab that name of the file so that I can display it to the user.
I've tried to check the input field with a jQuery selector, but nothing about it changes when a file has been selected. I searched the page of html for the file name and nothing returned.
Of course, this needs to be done before the image has been submitted but after it has been selected. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: So, you want the filename on user choose a file on a client side?

Comment: Yes. I basically just want to show them what file they have chosen. Right now, they just choose a file and nothing changes for them until they push the submit button.

Comment: Can you check something like **$("#input_id").val()**? Do you see a value?

Answer (score 1):

ImageField inherits from FileField methods and attributes. Take a look in a similar question for FileField:

[FileField Size and Name in Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082652/filefield-size-and-name-in-template)